# Getting back strange JSON array from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have the following PHP code:

```
$data=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notes WHERE rootNoteId='$noteId'");
$mainArray;
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($data))
{
    $mainArray[]=$result;
}

$sendback = array(
     "mainArray" => $mainArray
);
sendResponse(200, json_encode($sendback));
```

My table 'notes' has the following fields:

```
'noteId'
'authorName'
'noteBody'
```

However my return JSON string has the following format:

```
{
    "0": "3",
    "1": "Moe Bit",
    "2": "Sub sub ",
    "noteId": "3",
    "authorName": "Moe Bit",
    "noteBody": "Sub sub "
}
```

Why is it adding `0,1,2` indexes for the array with duplicate values of my table fields? I just want `noteId`, `authorName`, and `noteBody`-I'm not sure where it's coming up with `"0","1","2"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try either mysql_fetch_assoc or mysql_fetch_object

Answer (score 2):

[mysql_fetch_array()](http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array) in it's default "mode" fetches the result as associative & numeric array. So you get field names (what you want) and numeric indexes (the numbers you don't want).

To solve this pass the constant "MYSQL_ASSOC" as the second parameter to "mysql_fetch_array" or use the [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) function.